# Code a new variable for a dataset using multiple logical operators in R

Tags: r, sas, logical-operators

I am trying to convert SAS script to R to learn R. Below is the script in SAS.

```
if continent=1 and (country=5 or country=10) then rate = 8
```

Here are my attempts for the dataframe called *data*:

```
data$rate[(continent==1) & (country==5 | country==10)] <- 8
```

Or:

```
data$rate[(continent==1) & country %in% c(5,10)] <-8
```

Unfortunately, the attempts do not generate the result correctly. The result shows the rate 8 when either continent=1 or country=5 or country=10. I guess I am wrong on combining logical operators in R.

Could anyone help me fix the issue? Many thanks!

Note: I used attach(data) above since I am lazy to rewrite data again.

Comment: Without sample data, hard to reproduce. Try: `data$rate[(data$continent==1 & data$country==5 | data$country==10)] <- 8`

Comment: I think you're missing a comma `data$rate[(continent==1) & (country==5 | country==10),] <- 8`

Comment: `attach(data)` is a really bad idea in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue is that you did not call the variable from the data from the dataframe `data`. This may be the cause of your error. To fix this, specify the variable within the dataframe by doing:

`data$rate[(data$continent==1 & (data$country==5 | data$country==10))] <- 8`

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that Attach(data) is used above.

Comment: I would not use `attach`. If you do just put parentheses around the whole logical statement as shown above. i.e., `data$rate[((continent==1) & (country==5 | country==10))] <- 8`

Comment: Thank you for the correct solution. I missed the parentheses!